# SQL: How can I find Tuples with the same attribute?

Tags: sql

I have three tables

- `Seller` (ID, Name)
- `Product` (ID, description, tax)
- `Sells` (SellerID, ProductID, price)

How do I find the sellers who sell the same product for the same price?

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: What have you tried?  Sample data, desired results, and a query that you have tried improve any question.

Comment: @gexicide not homework. just wanted to learn sql and searched around for exercises and the samples at w3schools are not really challenging. May have been homework for someone else though

Comment: A hint: You need two sellers, two products, and two sells to compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
select x.SellerID ,y.SellerID
from sells x
join sells y
on x.ProductID = y.ProductID
and x.price = y.price
and x.SellerID <> y.SellerID
```

Comment: thanks! exactly what I was looking for. I'll try to play around with this using other queries/tables to get used to it